# What are the conditions to unlock all officers, soldiers, AFVs, and Metal Gears?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-motherbase

The Metal Gear Solid 5 companion app<sup>**1**</sup> has a minigame called *Mother Base*.

From the beginning, you only have Snake and Kaz as officers, and can only recruit or build the first unit listed in each respective list for soldiers, AFVs, and Metal Gears.

It appears that some of them are unlocked by playing and progressing through the minigame, such as officer Amanda and the *Armored Vehicle: Custom*; others are unlocked by performing specific actions in *Metal Gear Solid 5*<sup>**2**</sup>.

What are those actions, what do they unlock, and at what *Mother Base* player level do I unlock the rest? In other words: What are all available units in the minigame, and how do I unlock them all?

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: Currently available for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.konami.mgsvgzapp) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metal-gear-solid-v-ground/id821316090?mt=8).
<sup>**2**</sup>: Currently just *Ground Zeroes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Google Docs Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhQob9IBYgqPdHFwODcteHh0UnAxQV9XS3hqUkdUcVE&usp=sharing#gid=0) found on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/739463-metal-gear-solid-v-ground-zeroes/68847167):

## Officers

```
 1. Big Boss             Unlocked by default
 2. Kaz                  Unlocked by default
 3. Amanda               Player level 5
 4. Huey                 Player level 20
 5. Strangelove          Player level 40
 6. Cecile               Player level 60
 7. Solid Snake          Déjà Vu (PS3/PS4) [Hard] Score: 65 000
 8. Raiden               Jamais Vu (360/One) [Hard] Score: ???
 9. Cyborg Ninja         Déjà Vu (PS3/PS4) [Hard] Score: 85 000
10. Raiden (White Armor) Jamais Vu (360/One) [Hard] Score: ???
11. Naked Snake          All missions [Hard]: Stealth/No Kill Completion
12. Ocelot               Intel Operative Rescue [Hard] Score: ???
13. EVA                  Ground Zeroes: Mark all Enemies < 9 minutes
14. Volgin               Ground Zeroes [Hard] Score: ???
15. The Boss             All missions [Normal & Hard]: S-Rank
16. The Sorrow           Classified Intel Acquisition [Hard] Score: ???
17. The Pain             Send Enemy Flying: 20 meters
18. The Fear             Longest Headshot: 350 meters
19. The End              Longest Headshot (tranq. gun): 130 meters
20. The Fury             2-wheel time > 3 minutes
21. Major Zero           Destroy the Anti-Air Emplacements [Hard] Score: 50 000
22. Para-Medi            Eliminate the Renegade Threat [Hard] Score: 50 000
23. Sigint               Ground Zeroes: Neutralize all Enemies < 9 minutes
24. Sokolov              15 Rodent Exterminations
25. Granin               15 Crow Exterminations
```

## Soldiers

```
 1. Common Soldier       Barrack level 1
 2. Commando             Barrack level 3
 3. Heavy Armor Infantry Barrack level 6
 4. Sniper               Barrack level 9
 5. Ocelot Soldier       15 Prisoners rescued
```

## AFV

```
 1. AV: Standard         Factory level 1
 2. AV: Custom           Factory level 2
 3. AV: Heavy Standard   ???
 4. AV: Heavy Custom     Factory level 7
 5. Tank: Standard       Factory level 3
 6. Tank: Custom         Factory level 5
 7. Tank: Heavy Standard ???
 8. Tank: Heavy Custom   ???
 9. Heli: Standard       Factory level 4
10. Heli: Custom         ???
11. Heli: Heavy Standard Factory level 6
12. Heli: Heavy Custom   Factory level 10
13. Gekko                ??? Total Knock-Outs/Tranqs/Hold-Ups
```

## Metal Gear

```
 1. Pupa                 Hangar level 1
 2. Chrysalis            Hangar level 3
 3. Cocoon               Hangar level 5
 4. Peace Walker         Hangar level 7
 5. Metal Gear Zeke      Hangar level 9
 6. Metal Gear Rex       Longest Headshot: 300 meters
 7. Metal Gear Ray       Longest Headshot (tranq. gun): 75 meters
 8. Shagohod             15 missions completed
 9. Pupa: Custom         Ground Zeroes [Hard] Score: 75 000
10. Chrysalis: Custom    Eliminate the Renegade Threat [Hard] Score: 60 000
11. Cocoon: Custom       Classified Intel Acquisition [Hard] Score: 60 000
12. Peace Walker: Custom Intel Operative Rescue [Hard] Score: 20 000
13. MG Zeke: Custom      Destroy the Anti-Air Emplacements [Hard] Score: 55 000
```

Comment: Please don't leave link only answers.  Fully answer the question, and leave a link in order to cite your sources.

Comment: @MBraedley The answer was bad, but it still answered my question. Since I wasn't satisfied with the current quality of the answer, I decided to improve it myself. It just took me 2 weeks longer than I had anticipated :p